# eval(element.innerHTML) shows unexpected syntax error

Tags: javascript, eval

when i try to eval an equation which is an element.innerhtml. it works most of the time. but if the equation has for eg 9** it show an error in the console, as unexpected syntax error unexpected input error

like eval(div.innerHTML);

am i doing anything wrong

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: So what you're saying is, "when the equation has a syntax error, it complains that there's a syntax error"?

Comment: so it works for correct equations , but when the equations are not correct like 9**  it shows this error in console, how can i correct this

Comment: @emeryville simply, dont input incorrect equations.

Answer (score 2):

`9**` is not valid javascript, hence the error.

You could then try:

```
try {
  eval(div.innerHTML);
}
catch(e) {
  // handle error here
}
```

However, as @DaveChen pointed out, always remember that [**eval is evil**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: yes , in that case how would i handle the eval as this is coming from the user

Comment: @emeryville use try catch?

Comment: You might also want to point out that using eval is dangerous, because the user could put something like `window.close()` and it would close the window.

Comment: @DaveChen right! updated!

Comment: @DaveChen So the user can close their own browser window. Big whoop. If the source code were coming from *someone else* then it would be XSS and a massive problem, but for the user typing code into their own browser? Who cares!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The OP never said anything about the user typing code. But then again, he never said anything about code being loaded from an external source. I'm only assuming the worst, and this question is broad.